# BigQuery: How to aggregate multiple strings in a bigquery array

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working in bigquery where users are in multiple split tests (Screenshot below-- for each distinct split test a user_property is created with the format `firebase_exp_%` ). [image]

I want to create query that aggregates all tests with the corresponding user_pseudo_id.

so the expected output would be:
[image]

I have tried,

```
select 
    user_pseudo_id, 
    string_agg((select key from unnest(user_properties) where key like 'firebase_exp_%' ) as expagg from bigquery_eventtable 
    group by 1
and
 user_pseudo_id, 
    array_agg((select key from unnest(user_properties) where key like 'firebase_exp_%') as expagg from bigquery_eventtable 
    group by 1
```

but get this error:

[image]

Is there anyway to do this without a massive case statement?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
    user_pseudo_id,
    STRING_AGG(p.value)
FROM bigquery_eventtable e,
     UNNEST(user_properties) p
WHERE p.key LIKE 'firebase_exp_%'
GROUP BY e.user_pseudo_id
```

I don't have you schema, but it should be something like this.